# Go web server does not process /delete/ pattern correctly

Tags: go

I just played with a google GO official example [Writing Web Applications](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) I tried to add a functionality to delete pages and it has not worked. The reason is that if you pass `"/delete/"` as a parameter to `http.HandleFunc()` function you get always 404 Page not found. Any other `"foobar"` string works as expected.

**Simplified code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", r.URL.Path)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello/", handler)
    //http.HandleFunc("/delete/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Compile and call `http://localhost:8080/hello/world` from a browser
2. Output is `/hello/world`
3. Now comment `http.HandleFunc("/hello/", handler)` and uncomment `http.HandleFunc("/delete/", handler)`
4. Compile and call `http://localhost:8080/delete/world` from a browser
5. Result is `404 page not found`, expected `/delete/world`

**Question:**
Is there any special meaning for `"/delete/"` pattern? Is there any technical reason for that or is it just a bug?

Comment: Works as its supposed to do here ...

Comment: Strange. Environment issue? My is `go version go1.1.2 windows/amd64`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something which cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine here, and it cannot possibly work in one situation and not the other. You're just changing the string `"hello"` for the string `"delete"` between the two lines.

I suggest trying again more carefully. It must be a detail elsewhere.

---

The real reason was not checking the error result of `ListenAndServe`. An old copy was running in background, and the lack of error handling made it go unperceived. The browser was getting results from an old server.

Comment: It worked :( awkward.

Comment: Could be a cache issue.

Comment: Check the error result of `ListenAndServe`. I bet you had a copy running in background without realizing, and the lack of error handling made it go unperceived.